# PHP Debugging with Expressions?

Tags: php, debugging, expression

I am new to debugging and I'm very interested in knowing how to setup expressions in debugging environment. For example, if I want to see when a variable $a changes it value to non-empty, how would I find it out?

Comment: Do you want live debugging or just being able to output the final results of specific points to something visual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are looking for here.

If you wish to be able to output specific variables to a visual medium while running an application in PHP you can use an application like: http://www.firephp.org/ this will allow you to put debugging lines in your php and have them output to your browser.

However you are most likely (going by your question) looking for something that would allow you to set breakpoints and so forth while coding you are pretty much limited to zend studio (eclipse) http://shop.zend.com/en/zend-studio-for-eclipse.html

Bonus: for javascript debugging i suggest firebug

Comment: Hi, yes I'm already using Zend Studio, but I'm not sure how can I achieve this with it. I can see variable values over time, but I heard it's possible to make some kind of thing that executions until some variables changes it data to x. Of course this can be done manually, but I'm looking for an automatic solution.